# Video from camera set fixed dimensions on body and is damaging my responsive site

Tags: aframe, ar.js

Hi I have a responsive website. All the DIVs container depend of their parents and I use a lot width and height 100%.

I see that Arjs is setting fixed dimensions to the body.

[image]

I thought that I did something wrong but in the official example is happening the same:

[image]

My goal is to have some html elements on front of the camera but the fixed dimensions are affecting my CSS.  Is there a way to control this?

I tried this configuration for tests but I did not see any change:

```
arjs="sourceWidth:480; sourceHeight:480; displayWidth: 480; displayHeight: 480"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it using position "fixed" in all my elements.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "embedded" component on the  tag, it will remove the automatic css fullscreen styles that A-Frame adds by default. You can find more details [here in the documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/embedded.html).

Comment: See the official link on ARjs :   https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js/aframe/examples/marker-based/basic.html  , is happening the same even with embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Making position "fixed" in all elements is helpful but not enough.
And still making custom elements acting weird or overflow from the screen.

Simply add these may help:

```
html { 
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```